# Can't initialize environment variables for i3 exec script

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, i3

I have a script called `display`, which sets my desktop background using `feh`. It does so with the following line:

`feh --bg-scale $WALLPAPER &`

The environment variable $WALLPAPER is initialized in my `.bashrc`. The script works correctly if I execute it from an ordinary shell after login.

I want the script to be executed by i3 on startup. Therefore, I added the following line to `~/.config/i3/config`:

`exec display`

and it doesn't work. I tried to redirect STDERR to a file, and the result is:

```
feh: No loadable images specified.
See 'man feh' for detailed usage information
```

Moreover, if I try to `echo $WALLPAPER` inside `display`, I get a blank line. So the environment variable is not initialized yet. Fine - I tried to add `exec /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"` on the line above, but that seems to make no difference. How can I make sure this variable is initialized when i3 starts up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered for me [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/d0tyzk/cant_initialize_environment_variables_for_i3_exec/). The problem is that `.bashrc` is only loaded by bash - putting the environment variables in `~/.profile` means that it runs correctly.

Comment: Well `~/.profile` is loaded by `bash` as well, but only if there is no `~/.bash_profile` and if the shell is started as a login shell. The `sh` shell should also read `~/.profile` if it's started as a login shell. It's unclear what shell is running your i3 `config` file. Also, wouldn't running `feh` as a background job like that leave a lot of `feh` processes hanging around after a while?

Comment: I happened to check this, it seems to use `/bin/sh`. I don't think it will run many `feh`s, since the script is in the i3config file, which is only loaded once when i3 starts.

Answer (score 0):

Is i3 being executed by a different user, try providing an absolute path to the source command instead of relative path with ~

Comment: Running `ps -al | grep i3` returns `0 S  1000  4609  4591  0  80   0 - 38323 ep_pol tty2     00:00:00 i3`, with the UID being 1000 (which is my UID). So I think it's being run by me. 

Changing `~` to an absolute path also doesn't seem to make a difference, I'm afraid. 

It does make me realise however that it's finding the `display` script which is in `~/bin`, i.e. my PATH is being loaded correctly. Which is even more strange, since it's not loading other environment variables from startup.